# I need to generate a random number that does not repeat, python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am programming a bingo and I need to generate a number to fill each coordinate, right now I have an algorithm to give me random numbers but I need a way to make sure those numbers don't repeat themselves.

```
n=0
while n<=4:    
  x=random.randint(1,21)
  app.put_number(n,0,x,1)
  n=n+1
```

app.put_number is a predetermined function for this assignment.
the important thing is to make x not repeat itself the 5 times the algorithm r

Comment: `random.sample(list(range(1,21)),5)` should do then. Looking for the duplicate right now

Comment: i´ve read that thread but i dont know how to apply it to my code, i am a very basic programer and i dont know how to use each number individually that the code provides.

Comment: not a reason to reopen, but `app = random.sample(list(range(1,22)),5)` should create a list with 5 numbers between 1 & 21, they won't repeat.